# xslt 1.0 - Trying to get nodes for a specific value

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I've got an XML file that has many similarly named nodes but attributes within certain nodes are unique. I want to output into an HTML page only the nodes that fall under a certain attribute value.

Here is the xml:

```
<document>
  <component>
    <section>
      <templateId value="temp_1" />
      <entry>
        <act>
          <code displayName="temp_1:code_1" />
        </act>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <act>
          <code displayName="temp_1:code_2" />
        </act>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <act>
          <code displayName="temp_1:code_3" />
        </act>
      </entry>
    </section>
    <section>
      <templateId value="temp_2" />
      <entry>
        <act>
          <code displayName="temp_2:code_1" />
        </act>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <act>
          <code displayName="temp_2:code_2" />
        </act>
      </entry>
    </section>
  </component>
</document>
```

From this specific example, I want to only get the displayName value from the section that has the templateId value of temp_2. This is the XSL code that I'm using but it is getting everything, not just the section that I want. i know the first "when" is working because the right header (between the span tags) is displaying properly. It's just the for-each through the entries.

```
<xsl:tempalte match="/">
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="//templateId/@value='temp_2'">
    <div style="margin-bottom: 5px; padding: 5px; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;">
      <span style="font-weight: bold;">Template 2: </span>
      <br />
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="count(//section/entry) != 0">
          <xsl:for-each select="//section/entry">
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
                <xsl:value-of select="act/code/@displayName" />
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <br/>
                <xsl:value-of select="act/code/@displayName" />
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          No codes to display
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </div>
  </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

It should display like so:

```
temp_2:code_1
<br>temp_2:code_2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would help to see the output you expect to receive.

Comment: @ABach - added what the output should be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description it sounds like you only want the temp_2 values in your for-each.

That being the case you can just update your select to the following:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//section[templateId/@value = 'temp_2']/entry">
```

This says to grab any `entry` under `section` that has a `templateId` with an attribute of `value` that equals 'temp_2'.

Comment: Would I also put this in the when statement right above the for-each where I check the count to see if there is an entry? I need to check to see if there are any entries and if not, display the text in the otherwise.

Comment: Yes, you can. Otherwise your when test is looking at all of your section/entry instead of just the specific ones under temp_2.

Comment: Going with this one for now... working on deciphering the other answer from torazaburo for ease of use longer term. Thank you to both

Comment: @jjasper0729 torazaburo wanting you to use templates is definitely the right idea when making XSLT. However, for a simple one like this you are fine with the approach you have and with the update I recommend. But you will start to find that using templates gets a lot quicker and more efficient the more you use them so I would recommend you explore those more. You'll really like them once you figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to completely restudy XSLT and its philosophy. Don't program it like it was BASIC. The basic pattern, at least for your case, is that an XSLT program is a collection of templates to handle matching elements. Instead of littering your code with `if` and `choose`, write templates with the proper matching conditions. Instead of BASIC's `FOR I=1 TO 10`, use `<xsl:apply-templates/>` to "iterate" over the children. Here's the basic idea:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="templateId"/> <!-- skip templateID elements by default -->

<xsl:template match="templateId[@value='temp_2']">
    <div style="margin-bottom: 5px; padding: 5px; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;">          
        <span style="font-weight: bold;">Template 2: </span>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="code">
    <xsl:value-of select="@displayName"/>
    <xsl:if test="position() != 1"><br/></xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="section[count(entry)=0]">
    No codes to display
</xsl:template>
```

Why no template for `act` elements? Well, by default XSLT will provide you with a template which does a `<xsl:apply-templates/>`.

Comment: I'm just getting into XSLT from a vb.net background so my thinking is in the .net progression. How would this work if I wanted to also output Template 1 but with a different layout from what you have here for Template 2?

Comment: so what I SHOULD have is for each different type of output for different nodes (not just these in this example as it's a snippet of a much large xml file) a template that fits the needs and works down through the xml document node set? The <xsl:apply-templates> that you have, that goes through all of the ones below where its' called from? could it be specific so that different sections would have their own templates? If that makes it easier to read and follow then that's more helpful to me.

Comment: Add another template `<xsl:template match=templateId[@value='temp_1']">`.

Comment: so adding another template for temp_1, if I want to have it displayed after temp_2, I just put it below in the xsl file? Can I apply specific templates with the xsl:apply-templates that are defined in the xsl file?

Comment: @jjasper0729 1. Yes. You won't go too far wrong thinking of an XSLT program as a series of templates, one for each specific type of element you want to process in a certain way. 2. Yes, you can name templates and call them by name, but you won't normally need or want to do that. That's the procedural mindset, where you have named "subroutines" you call. In general, you can do almost all of what you want to do by just letting XSLT do what it does best, which is matching templates.

Comment: The basic <xsl:apply-templates/> would just sequence through all the templates I have below the main one, correct? That way I could basically build each different template for each section that I want to output? I know I can put a "select" with the xpath information in to a <xsl:apply-templates> tag. Is that more of the procedural mindset to match the xpath in the select attribute with the match attribute of my other template? I may have to output information on the web page in a different order from the xml document (and it's a big, nasty many node level document). Thanks again for the help

Comment: To be precise, `<xsl:apply-templates/>` matches children against *all* templates, not just the ones below. Yes, you can use the `select` attribute to `<xsl:apply-templates/>`, and yes, that is often the mark of a procedural mindset, but if you are indeed processing things from the input in different order, then you would probably need to do that.

Comment: I have been working with the <xsl:apply-templates /> the last day or so. The select attribute is vital for this particular xsl application because the xml document is quite large and very complex and the display order is quite different from the sequence in the xml document. But I think I'm getting the hang of the templates and being able to pick and choose what displays based on the match. It does make it a lot cleaner in the code than all the choose/when and for-each. Thanks for the insight.